# Graphics HatchFilling not working, Causes crash

Tags: graphics, crash, error-tracking

I cannot use [`HatchFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html) in my *Mathematica v13.0.1 on Windows*.

Whenever I use it, **both *Mathematica*'s front end and Kernel crash**.

When I open the documentation related to `HatchFilling` it opens but when I scroll down *Mathematica* crashes.

Version: 13.0.1.0

OS: Windows

Minimum example that causes the problem:

```
Graphics[{HatchFilling[],Disk[]}]
```

- **Can anybody reproduce this crash on other systems?**
- **Is there any workaround?**

Comment: @bmf No it doesn't. It crashes.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem in `13.2.0`

Comment: I would say that all crashes are a bug, an unacceptable behaviour for any software. You should contact Wolfram Support for this. Best case scenario people here may help narrow down the conditions to reproduce this and find a workaround. So far I can not reproduce you problem.  When you have new information to improve your question, always add it to the question. The comments sections are for comments, not to complement the question, which should be self-sufficient. Probable you can delete the obsolete comments.

Comment: `HatchFilling` is a pixel shader, so it requires your GPU to generate the image.  I would start by updating your video card driver.